# Scala (Shell): java.lang.InternalError: Malformed class name

Tags: java, scala, gson, flink-streaming

I am the new player on scala and trying on the `Gson` package for `case class` to `JSON` string. I have two environments to work on this. Both are running the same code.

The code is:

```
//package flink

import com.google.gson.Gson

object HelloWorld {
  case class OutputMeasurements(
                                 TotalYield : Double,
                                 TotalYield_delta: Double,
                                 is_init: Int,
                                 is_reset: Int
                               )

  case class OutputSchema(
                           site: String,
                           measurements: OutputMeasurements,
                           rec_time: String
                         )
  def ToJsonString(dataClass: OutputSchema): String ={
    val gson = new Gson
    val jsonString = gson.toJson(dataClass)
    return jsonString
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
    val x = OutputMeasurements(10, 20, 3, 4)
    val y = OutputSchema("a", x, "bcd")
    println(ToJsonString(y))
  }
}
```

First, local, using `IntelliJ IDEA` to compile the `jar` with `maven`, then its success.
Return:

```
Hello, world!
{"site":"a","measurements":{"TotalYield":10.0,"TotalYield_delta":20.0,"is_init":3,"is_reset":4},"rec_time":"bcd"}
```

Second, Using the local compiled jar as library (`flink.jar`) copy into K8S pod and running in scala shell to test/POC.

Docker Image: `flink:1.11.2-scala_2.11`

Running Shell: `bin/start-scala-shell.sh remote localhost 8081 -a /opt/flink/flink.jar`

JavaVersion:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_275-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
```

Running CMD:

```
<copy and paste the code of object HelloWorld>
HelloWorld.main(Array("test"))
```

Return:

```
Hello, world!
java.lang.InternalError: Malformed class name
  at java.lang.Class.getSimpleName(Class.java:1330)
  at java.lang.Class.isAnonymousClass(Class.java:1411)
  at com.google.gson.internal.Excluder.isAnonymousOrLocal(Excluder.java:226)
  at com.google.gson.internal.Excluder.excludeClassChecks(Excluder.java:202)
  at com.google.gson.internal.Excluder.create(Excluder.java:113)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:696)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:683)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:638)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:618)
  at HelloWorld$.ToJsonString(<console>:92)
  at HelloWorld$.main(<console>:100)
  ... 30 elided
```

Is it the scala shell issue? how can I successfully run in scala shell to POC/testing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried flink.HelloWorld.main (giving also the package name)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the case class `OutputMeasurements` and `OutputSchema` *outside* the object `HelloWorld` ?

This could be related to the issue https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/5425

Comment: I tried and return the same result. It seems related to `Gson` package issue?